# What caused this post to bump to the front page?

Tags: support, specific-question, editing

I was browsing the front page and [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/120701/160331) showed up as "Modified 1 hour ago". I almost replied thinking it was an active post, but it's from 2016 and there doesn't seem to be anything new on it. This is mostly to just satiate my own curiosity, but what caused this post to bump? There's no new edits, no new comments and no new answers, at least that I can see. It was also protected 2 years ago. @Marc.2377 is the person who shows up as the modifier.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that user made an edit to his answer on that question. This is how StackExchange works.

Comment: Oh god I'm dumb. I didn't look at the answers to see if there were edits.